# Foreach key value loop (to manage PHP Object)

Tags: php, object, for-loop

```
object(stdClass)#150 (3) {
  ["id_definicion"]=>
  NULL
  ["id_termino"]=>
  string(3) "373"
  ["definicion"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#151 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(271) "Grupo de personas influyentes, organizado para presionar en favor de    determinados intereses. La actividad se denomina lobbying y quien la practica lobbista.<br   />Un ejemplo de lobby turÃ­stico en EspaÃ±a es Exceltur; el Skal Club serÃ­a un lobby turÃ­stico internacional."
  }
}
object(stdClass)#151 (3) {
  ["id_definicion"]=>
  NULL
  ["id_termino"]=>
  string(3) "373"
  ["definicion"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#150 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(119) "VestÃ­bulo de un hotel y de otros establecimientos como cines, teatros,   restaurantes, etc., especialmente si es grande."
  }
}
```

Seeing the code above I am having trouble to insert the values into my database of the second object which is inside of the first object. Im not sure how im suppose to manage an object inside another to be able to insert them.

This is the code I use to insert into the database, its very short and brief:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$termino = new stdClass;
$termino->id_definicion = NULL;
$termino->id_termino = $idtermino;
$termino->definicion = $definicion;

$db->insertObject( '#__csglosario_definiciones', $termino);
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are you asking how to access the value of the `SimpleXMLElement` object? What does this have to do with `for` loops?

Comment: Yes exactly. I was told the best way to access one of these elements was using a foreach? I might be mistaken..

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php for how to iterate through an object rather than an array. You can only do it if the class implements `Iterable` or the properties are public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$termino->definicion = (string)$definicion;

Comment: Thanks Raul Duran, that was pretty easy! Helped alot!